# Create file fails

Tags: java, file-io

I have a webservice running on tomcat, and want to execute some fileIO.

```
File f = new File(test.txt);
new BufferedReader(new FileReader(test.txt));
```

result:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.txt
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
```

Am I missing something? Running my code as a local standalone app works as expected. But on tomcat results in exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to create the file first. A File object is actually just a representation of a file's path, not the file itself.

```
f.createNewFile()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!f.exists())  
{  
   f.createNewFile();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Running my code as a local standalone app works as expected. But on tomcat results in exception.

You are using a path relative to the working directory. When you run it as a stand alone app, I assume you have the file in the directory you run the app from.  The working directory for a web server is often the `bin` of the server so you are saying you expect the file to be there.

Using a full path, or using a resource of your application with getResourceAsInputStream() is a better idea.